# JSON-B serializes Map keys using toString and not with registered Adapter

Tags: jsonb, jsonb-api

I have a JAX-RS service that returns a `Map<Artifact, String>` and I have registered a

```
public class ArtifactAdapter implements JsonbAdapter<Artifact, String>
```

which a see hit when deserializing the in-parameter but not when serializing the return value, instead the Artifact toString() is used. If I change the return type to a Artifact, the adapter is called. I was under the impression that the Map would be serialized with built-in ways and then the adapter would be called for the Artifact.

What would be the workaround? Register an Adapter for the whole Map?

I dumped the thread stack in my toString and it confirms my suspicions

```
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1336)
Artifact.toString(Artifact.java:154)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.MapSerializer.serializeInternal(MapSerializer.java:41)
at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.MapSerializer.serializeInternal(MapSerializer.java:30)
at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:63)
at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Marshaller.serializeRoot(Marshaller.java:118)
at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Marshaller.marshall(Marshaller.java:74)
at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.toJson(JsonBinding.java:98)
```

is the serializer hell-bent on using toString at this point?

I tried

```
public class Person {
private String name;

public Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

}

public class PersonAdapter  implements JsonbAdapter{

```
@Override
public String adaptToJson(Person obj) throws Exception {
    return obj.getName();
}

@Override
public Person adaptFromJson(String obj) throws Exception {
    return new Person(obj);
}
```

}

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Person, Integer> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put(new Person("John"), 23);

    JsonbConfig config = new JsonbConfig().withAdapters(new PersonAdapter());
    Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create(config);
    System.out.println(jsonb.toJson(data, new HashMap<Person, Integer>() {
    }.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()));
}
```

}

but still ended up with the toString() of Person

Thanks in advance,
  Nik

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/yasson/issues/110 (in my case since that's the default provider for WildFly)